# C Console Program using User Input ('+' / '-') for Mathematical operations not functioning

Tags: c, if-statement, scanf

I made this program but it doesn't work.

You enter two numbers.
Then you press + or -.
If you press + it should add the numbers.
If you press - it should  subtract.
But that part doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
char opt;       
int a,b,s;      
scanf("%d",&a);
scanf("%c\n",&opt);  
scanf("%d",&b); 
if(opt=='+') {           //this part doesn't work
s=a+b;
}
else if(opt=='-') {
s=a-b;
}
printf("%d",s);
 return 0;
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: just input as 12+13 with no spaces in between, it will work

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d",&a);
getchar();
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove \n from this line.. 
scanf("%c\n",&opt);
So it will be... 
scanf("%c",&opt);

Answer (score -1):

When you are using the conversion specifier `%c` then scanf reads all characters including white spaces.

Use the following call

```
scanf( " %c", &opt );
        ^^^
```

See the blank before the `'%'` symbol and the absent symbol `'\n'`.